# Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

After implemented Private Route I keep getting this error.

The problem appears when Im trying to get to the Profile page that nested in the .

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import SignUpPage from './pages/SignUpPage';
import ProfilePage from './pages/ProfilePage';
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage';
import AboutPage from './pages/AboutPage';
import AdditionalItemPage from './pages/AdditionalItemPage';
import ReturnOfVehiclePage from './pages/ReturnOfVehiclePage';
import PolicyPage from './pages/PolicyPage';
import CarPage from './pages/CarPage';
import CarListPage from './pages/CarsListPage';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import Footer from './Footer';
import NotFoundPage from './pages/NotFoundPage';
import { PrivateRoute } from './auth/PrivateRoute';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUpPage />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
            <Route path="/cars" element={<CarListPage />} />
            <Route path="/cars/:carId" element={<CarPage />} />
            <Route path="/additional-item" element={<AdditionalItemPage />} />
            <Route path="/return-vehicle" element={<ReturnOfVehiclePage />} />
            <Route path="/policy" element={<PolicyPage />} />
            <Route
              path="/profile"
              element={
                <PrivateRoute>
                  <ProfilePage />
                </PrivateRoute>
              }
            />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PrivateRoute.js comp

```
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useUser } from './useUser';

export const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const user = useUser();

  if (!user) return <Navigate to="/login" />;

  return <Route {...props} />;
};
```

I've already tried to wrap everyting I though of in the 
The actual Profile paga into Routes
The PrivteRoute into Routes
The Route into another Routes
Creating another Routes, separeted with the 1st one.

If remove PrivateRoute, everything works fine but it s not the solution I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just didn't  implement it properly , just change your **PrivateRoute.js component** like this  :

```
import {  Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useUser } from './useUser';
function PrivateRoute({ children }) {
  const user = useUser();
  return user ? children : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is accurate in that a `Route` must be directly placed within a `Routes` wrap. To get around this, simply create a 2nd top-level `Routes` wrap and move the `Route` logic out of your `PrivateRoute.tsx` file.

Consider [this example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/typescript-react18-2-private-route-bw2cke) I created with some slight modifications to your code. You can switch `user` to false/true to see how the `/profile` private route reacts as expected.

Here's the bare-bones implementation:

**App.tsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoutes from "./PrivateRoutes";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<div>Hello World</div>} />
          </Routes>
          <PrivateRoutes /> {/* <---- all private routes ---- */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**PrivateRoutes.tsx**

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";

export default function PrivateRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/profile"
        element={
          <PrivateRoute>
            <div>Private Profile</div>
          </PrivateRoute>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

**PrivateRoute.tsx**

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

interface PropsI {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export default function PrivateRoute({ children }: PropsI) {
  const user = false;

  if (!user) return <Navigate to="/fail" />;

  return <>{children}</>;
}
```